# Object attribute not accessible, but there

Tags: javascript

I've got a data storage object, which basically stores data in its 'attributes' item.

```
datastorage = {
    attributes: {
        51: {/*data, another object*/}
    }
}
```

When I log datastorage.attributes to the console I get the expected result.
However when I try to access attributes[51] or attributes['51'] or even change the name to attributes['cert_51'] it will always be undefined.

I can't even loop through datastorage.attributes, either  it doesn't iterate even once or all I get is the datastorage.attributes object over and over.

```
$.each(datastorage.attributes, function (name, content) {
    console.log(name, content, this);
    // -> 0, {51:{..}}, {51:{..}
    $.each(this, function () {
         console.log(this);
         // -> {51:{..}}
    });
});
```

Any hints?

Comment: Hum... [I see no problem](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/rPPJz/)

Comment: Can you build a fiddle or complete code giving the "undefined" result ?

Comment: ^ thats utterly strange, I guess it's something in my code then. I'll try to isolate the bug and post back, thanks so far.
(could've just fiddled that myself, duh)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qknH4/ this is what I'm basically doing, and it works on the fiddle but not in my project, I guess I have to look further.

Comment: @denoir: You don't read before you add because of some asynchronous stuff?

Comment: @Bergi look at my answer below, that was indeed the problem. Was a bit sleepy when I wrote that code :p

Comment: Next time think before you post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.. I was loading the attributes in question asynchroniously and forgot about that.
I implemented a callback that will provide the value of the attribute once it's set.